# What method should I use for prediction of NUMBER_OF_ORDERS(TIME, LAT, LNG)?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, linear-model, spatio-temporal

I'm running a pizza service and would like to predict a number of orders for every hour interval during a day per location (basically where we should deliver the pizza) in future.

And I've got a pretty big data set of past orders: pairs of [timestamp, location], where location is a pair of latitude and longitude.

So I've got NUMBER_OF_ORDERS(TIME, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE) function. What's the most simple yet accurate method to use for this task?

I was told that linear regression is a bad choice because number of pizza orders is not a linear function of either time or locations.

Comment: Spatio-temporal data analysis is its own sub-field. This textbook is a good place to start. https://www.amazon.com/Statistics-Spatio-Temporal-Data-Noel-Cressie/dp/0471692743/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1526485990&sr=8-1&keywords=spatiotemporal+data

Comment: This is a hard problem to solve, and it depends on how much accuracy you want. For a pizza service a linear regression model might work well.

Comment: @Sycorax could you recommend some nice repo on github / some concise research paper? I've found a huge number of formulas and they're all pretty complicated (+ without the code itself). I even tried to search for 'spatio-temporal data bike nyc dataset' (append some random dataset trying to find a small pet project with code).

Comment: @knk do you really think LR model will work? E.g. if I fix location and select timestamps within one day I probably should get (/\ instead of a straight line, where '/\' means non-zero number of orders in the afternoon and about zero in the morning).

Comment: @J.Doe This is not a field which has yet coalesced around simple APIs in the same way that `sklearn` collects common, generic classifiers. The reason is that there are complex relationships among observations which are explicitly a part of the modeling problem. That makes the math hard, and it makes designing generic software hard, too - because you need to present those relationships and model them.

Comment: @Sycorax what do you think about using https://github.com/facebook/prophet? It seems like a great fit for me ("Tool for producing high quality forecasts for time series data that has multiple seasonality with linear or non-linear growth.") and there's a note in research paper it detects a weekly/yearly seasonal component what.

E.g. create a time series for each zone (group locations by zone (lat, long)) separately.

Comment: Could work. You'd be losing information about how the zones are related to each other (since we'd expect adjacent zones to be similar). If the zones are heterogenous, you might have very different effects within them -- like if a college dorm is in the same zone as an office park, each address will have radically different pizza consumption.